# ld script does not link objects from my lib with INPUT command

Tags: linker-errors, ld, linker-scripts

I have the small `ld` linker script bellow that is used to build a  x86 bootloader.

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
SECTIONS
{
        . = 0x7c00;

        .code :
    {
                * (.text)
        * (.rodata)
    }

    . = 0x7c00 + 510;

    .signature :
        {
            BYTE(0x55)
        BYTE(0xAA)
    }

}
STARTUP(crt0.o)
INPUT(-lfoo)        /* This is not working. */

/* INPUT(foo.o)*/   /* This works, instead. */
```

My program references the symbol `bar` from `foo.o`, which is a member of `libfoo.a`.
I tried to use `INPUT(-lfoo)` so that I don't need to pass `-lfoo` at the `ld` command line.
However, `ld` is unabled to resolve the symbol and I get this error message:

`undefined reference to` bar`

The only way it works is if I comment the `INPUT(-lfoo)` line and uncomment the next line, `INPUT(foo.o)`, which passes the object explicitly rather than the static library.

I vaguely suspect that it has to do with the order in which the linker will process the `-l` argument, but I'm not sure.

What is wrong, and what would be a workaround (if any) to use the form `INPUT(-lfoo)` in this example?

I tried changing `INPUT()` with `GROUP()` with no avail.
Either I have to pass `-lfoo` at `ld` command-line, or I need to pass the individual objects to `INPUT()`.